# Inexplicable error arrizing in Node.JS server using Express for HTML server and Formidable for multipart from processing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, formidable

As part of a larger project, I need to upload an image and some text field  to my server using a singular HTML POST form. To do this, I elected to use Formidable to process the data. However, when I do this, the program throws an inexplicable error. This error is that when running the line `var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();`, the application says that `formidable.IncomingForm()` is not a valid constructor. The reason that this is so mind boggling to me is that this is the way that every piece of documentation for Formidable says to initialize a form. If you could help me out, that would be great.

```js
//Adds new rock to database
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');

const formidable = require('express-formidable');
//const pool = require('../pool_handler');

router.use(formidable());

console.log('fileUpload module loaded');
/* POST page. */

router.post('/', function(req, result, next) {
 console.log('inside POST request');

 console.log(req.files);

 if(!req.files) {
  return next('/success');
 }

 var form =  formidable.IncomingForm();

 console.log('after the form issue');

 form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
  var oldpath = files.image.path;
  var newpath = '../public/images/' + files.image.name;
  fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function(err) {
   if(err) {
    throw err;
   }
  });

 });

 next('/success');
 
});

router.all('/', function(req, result) {
 result.render('addNewRock');
});

router.all('/success', function(req, result) {
 result.send('success!');
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am apology for my english, I am not write very well. But I expected to help you.

In my case I try to use that library (express-formidable) but it has very problems to compatibility and is very dificult solve them.

My sugestion is use the library "formidable", that provides all funtionality that you need and the page from npm contains all info that for implement.

Check [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)